# Update a date with the current month and year, but always keep the same day

Tags: excel, date

In Excel I have:

- (H10) Constant -----------17/04/2015 --------Been updating the month manually.
- (H11) Day Counter -------28 -----------------=DAY(TODAY())
- (H13) Last Update -------17/04/2015 ------=IF(H11=17, EDATE(H13,1), H10)

I can get the H13 to update to the new month by adding `1` to the month but once the counter moves off 17 it reverts back to the old date H10.

Is there any way in Excel to keep the `17th` constant and update only the month and year every 17th?

Comment: What are you trying to do here. it is not very clear to me. Forget the formulas you have, just state your input and your expected output, and the logic of the expected output. Also your function `=IF(H11=17, EDATE(H13,1), H10)` has cell `H13` is recursive, which is a problem in excel. It is like putting in cell `A1` the following function `=A1` i.e `A1` is equal to itself.

Comment: You could say *if Day was greater than 16* but what would you do at the end of the month and the day goes to *1*?

Comment: Input - 17/04/2015, Expected Output - 17/05/2015. Logic - On the 17th of each month update the current month and year, but leave the 17th the same date.

Comment: On the 18th what should happen? and the 16th and below i guess the date should remain the same?

Comment: Perhaps a better way to put it is I would like to have the 17th be a constant, and the month and year to always be up-to-date

Comment: On the any other day that isn't the 17th it should be 17/CurrentMonth/CurrentYear

Comment: Trying your solution now, thanks

Comment: Try this, i think i got it, `=IF(DAY(H10)=17, DATE(YEAR(H10), MONTH(H10)+1, 17), DATE(YEAR(H10), MONTH(H10), 17))`

Comment: When the date changes to 01/05/2015 the month goes up by 1, and when the date is 17/05/2015 it goes up again by 1 and back down by 1 on the 18/05/2015. So it appears to be working for the later half of the month

Comment: Sorry for missing this one, when I tried your formula I got this date, 17/12/3799

Comment: Is it clearer if I say I'm looking for a field that always has the current month and year, but keeps the date as 17th regardless. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want a cell to automatically always show the **next** 17th of the month (i.e. the next one after today) then you can use this stand alone formula

`=EOMONTH(TODAY()-16,0)+17`

format with required date format

That will display `17-May-2015` until we reach 17th May, at which point it will change to `17-June-2015`, and it will keep updating every month

Comment: I want the current month and year to be displayed, keeping the 17th date constant

Comment: Can I amend what you have sent to accommodate this? Appreciate the help.

Comment: In your question you said you wanted it to update on17th, is that incorrect? You want it to update on 1st of the month? pnuts suggestion will do that, or you can use `=EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+17`

Comment: @barry houdini does yours update on the 17th? I've grabbed both formulas but it looks like yours will be the fix, I'm testing both, thanks!

Comment: Yes, as I said in my answer - that formula (the one in my answer) will currently give you 17th May - once we reach 17 May it will change to 17 June and then do that every month - to test use a cell ref instead of today, e.g. `=EOMONTH(A1-16,0)+17` then see what results you get with various dates in A1

Comment: Is it clearer if I say I'm looking for a field that always has the current month and year, but keeps the date as 17th regardless. ?

Comment: That's the same as saying it changes on 1st of the month, isn't it? If you want 17th May to be displayed throughout May, then as soon as it gets to 1st June it changes to 17th June and displays that all through June etc. then pnuts formula in the comments above will do that - or use EOMONTH like this: =EOMONTH(TODAY(),0)+17